# Continuous Time Markov Chain Question

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A salesman flies between Atlanta, Boston, and Chicago as the following rates:

\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 2 & 2  \\
1 & -4 & 3  \\
5 & 0 & -5
\end{bmatrix}

(a) If the salesman takes a trip out of Atlanta, what is the probability of it being a trip to Chicago? (b) What is the expected time spent in Atlanta?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. For (a), how do I obtain the probabilities from the transition rate matrix provided? Or is there another way to calculate this probability? Any hints/advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "rates" mean? What do the entries in that matrix mean? For example, what does the $3$ in that matrix mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is a continuous-time Markov chain where the matrix is the transition rate matrix. That is, $q(i, j)$ is called a jump rate from $i$ to $j$ if $q(i, j) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{p_{h}(i, j)}{h}$ for $i \neq j$. So $q(i, j)$ describes the rates at which jumps are made $i$ to $j$. The 3 in the matrix is the rate at which jumps are made from Boston to Chicago.

Comment: Also $p_{h}(i, j) = p(X_h = j \mid X_0 = i)$.

Comment: So jumps are made from Atlanta to Atlanta at a rate of minus four? What does that mean?

Comment: If $i = j$, then $q(i, i) = -\sum_{j \neq i} q(i, j) = \lambda_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Atlanta means the top row. You see the jump rates to the other two cities are the same. So the probability to transit to either city is $1/2$.

In general just imagine that there are independent exponential times $T_{ij}$ for different possible transitions from state $i$ to state $j$, which have the rates specified in the generator. We wait for the first appearance of those times (i.e. the minimum), and that decide which is the next state to jump. So the transition probability from state $i$ to state $j$ can be thought as the probability that $T_{ij}$ is smallest among the other.

See the formula here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Embedded_Markov_chain

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a little unsure of how to calculate the expected value though. Say that $v_i$ is the rate at which the process makes a transition when in state
$i$, does that mean $v_i = \sum_{j} q(i, j)$? And would that make the expected value $\frac{1}{v_i}$? That is, $v_A = 4$, so $E[V_A] = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Yes it looks good. Since the staying time is the minimum of exponential, the expected staying time is the reciprocal of the absolute value of diagonal entry (as the minimum of exponential is still exponential with the rate equal to sum of individual rates, and the diagonal is the sum of the other entries inside that row, taking negative value)